# Get SQL query count in peewee

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

Is it possible to count queries in peewee?
Make it in Django as follows:

```
from django.db import connection
print len(connection.queries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can act just like  [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#adding-a-new-database-driver): subclass `Database` setting it up to count queries:

```
def execute(*args, **kwargs):
    self.counter += 1  # or put the query into some list, as you like
    return super().execute(args, kwargs)
```